# My app won't recognize keystrokes sent from SendKeys or SendInput, but does from the Keyboard

Tags: c#, keyboard, sendkeys, sendinput

I've got a homegrown app (Master) that has a bunch of hotkeys defined. I need to automate the app with another external app (Control). I cannot rebuild the Master app, it runs, is already installed and can't be messed with.

Using hotkeys on Master works like a charm if I use a keyboard.

So, I figure I an use SendKeys.SendWait or SendKeys.Send to send the commands. While my code works fine with other apps (such as Notepad) it is not working with my custom app, Master. This could be for a number of reasons - Master is older, has .NET, C++ mixed... some low level video controls... who knows what's under the covers.

I need to get something higher level. I need to be able to send the keystrokes as if they are coming from the keyboard itself. I don't want the computer to be able to differentiate between the physical keyboard sending the keys and my app sending the keys.

What can I use and how will it be different?

Comment: I don't know if this can solve your problem, but it never failed with me: [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/)

Comment: @Marco. Thanks for the advice. We are actually going to try using AutoHotKey tomorrow although I really wish I can figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Are you on Vista?  "The SendKeys class has been updated for the .NET Framework 3.0 to enable its use in applications that run on Windows Vista. The enhanced security of Windows Vista (known as User Account Control or UAC) prevents the previous implementation from working as expected. "

Comment: It is WinXP and we are using .NET 3.5. Again, we can control other apps on the machine, just not this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not SendKeys.

I tried SendKeys.Send, SendKeys.SendWait, SendInput and keybd_event.

I later realized that the time between activating the application and the time sending the keystrokes was too short. I was waiting 200ms but simply by increasing this to 500ms I solved my problem.

The application took a long time to draw because of the embedded video players. Giving it another 300ms allowed it to be ready for the keystrokes I was sending it.

Comment: FWIW, you've still got a race condition.

Comment: Agreed. It will get us through the tradeshow that starts in 12 hours, but eventually we will integrate into the app itself.

Comment: Use Process.WaitForInputIdle()